# Drupal Multi-Module Combinations for Cool Effects

Tags: drupal, content-management-system, drupal-modules

I am looking for a better understanding what **truely** can be done with Drupal modules. Specifically, module combinations that do something practical, specific to a need, and very cool.

Links to sites implementing these are appreciated.

+1 for creative and practical uses

Comment: That's a *very* open ended question given that if you can do it in PHP, you can do it in a Drupal Module.

Answer (score 2):

Drupal sites from creator of drupal: http://buytaert.net/tag/drupal-sites

p.s. Practical, specific to a need, and very cool is given by mix of drupal core, contributed modules, custom developed modules and custom theming.

Answer (score 1):

[Managing News](http://managingnews.com/) is a Drupal system with a lot of interconnected modules that makes a pretty impressive end product.

Answer (score 0):

features are (usually) made out of cck+views.
and you can find many use-oriented features out there. checkout for feature servers...
http://community.featureservers.org/
http://features.pingv.com/